# MapWritable replacing ALL existing keys with newly added ones - Hadoop MapReduce 2.6.4

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, hashmap

I am working with Hadoop 2.6.4 and I am trying to implement a Stripes mapper for word Co-Occurances. I am running into an issue when attempting to use `MapWritable` class. When trying to add new key/values into the map, any key that is added is replacing every single other key in the map with itself.

For example, let's say I have a sentence like
"This is a sentence with two a letters"

The first run through, I am looking at the co-occurrences for the word "This". So the expected mapper would be

```
<is,1>
<a,2>
<sentence,1>
<with,1>
<two,1>
<letters,1>
```

But what is actually happening is on each iteration of adding the subsequent words, ALL keys/values are being replaced with the last key that was added. The actual result I am seeing is the following.

```
<letters,1>
<letters,1>
<letters,1>
<letters,1>
<letters,1>
<letters,1>
```

I have created a method to convert a `HashMap` to `MapWritable`, this is where the issue is occurring. Here is the code I am using. I have added print statements to make sure the values I am adding are correct (they are) and then I am printing the keys to see what is occurring as I am adding them. This is where I was able to see that it is replacing each key as it adds a new one.

According to all documentation I have looked at, I am using `MapWritable.put()` properly, and it should simply be adding to the map or updating the value, as it would with a generic `HashMap`. I am at a loss as to what is causing this.

```
public static MapWritable toMapWritable(HashMap<String,Integer> map){

  MapWritable mw = new MapWritable();
  Text key = new Text();
  IntWritable val = new IntWritable();

  for(String it : map.keySet()){
      key.set(it.toString());
      System.out.println("Setting Key: " + key.toString());
      val.set(map.get(it));
      System.out.println("Setting Value: " + map.get(key.toString()));
      mw.put(key,val);
      for(Writable itw : mw.keySet()){
          System.out.println("Actual mw Key " + itw.toString());
      }
  }

  return mw;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling key.set() repeatedly and you have only allocated one Text. This is basically what you are doing.

```
Text key = new Text();
key.set("key1");
key.set("key2");
System.out.println(key); // prints 'key2'
```

I believe you might be implementing the common pattern of reusing objects in a Map/Reduce job. However, that hinges upon calling context.write(). For instance:

```
private Text word = new Text();
private IntWritable count = new IntWritable(1);

public void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context) {
  for (String s : line.toString().split(" ")) {
    word.set(s);
    context.write(word, count); // Text gets serialized here
  }
}
```

In the above example, the Map/Reduce framework will serialize that text to bytes and save them behind the scenes. That's why you are free to reuse the Text object. MapWritable does not do the same thing however. You need to create new keys each time.

```
MapWritable mw = new MapWritable();
mw.put(new Text("key1"), new Text("value1"));
mw.put(new Text("key2"), new Text("value2"));
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the exact issue.